# User analytics based on feature support instead of browser versions, etc

Tags: analytics, browser-feature-detection

If you have done any CSS or JavaScript you should know to rely on browser features and not brand and version.

```
if supports websockets do something
```

and not

```
if not ie do something
```

**Question**: Do you know if any ‘modern’ analytics tools that registers these features?

All I see is: Browser, Version, JavaScript support, resolution, all that which shouldn’t matter. I would sure like to know for instance what percentage of my users that supported ‘border-radius’.

Sure I could gather that info myself, but why do it if somebody else did already :)